# MS Access query making sure Higher retails match

Tags: database, ms-access, formula

I'm trying to build a query in MS Access and having an issue figuring out the best way to build it. What I'm trying to do is is make sure all the Higher retails match within a set of matching pack numbers. For example:

```
PackNum  Prefix    Retail
6451618  DF        37.99
6451618  SK        37.99
6451618  VJ        34.99
6451618  SG        37.99
```

One of the group is off and I want the query to show it.
I was attempting to use something like this to have check but I'm not getting the results I'm looking for

```
 IIf([dbo_PIC704Current]![PackNum]=[dbo_PIC704Current]![PackNum] 
 And [dbo_PIC704Current]![Ret2]<>[dbo_PIC704Current]![Ret2],True,False)
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
-Deke

Comment: How do you know which is the wrong one?

Comment: It doesn't match the other retails. they should all match or be essentially be the max of the grouping. it doesn't necessarily need to change it though, just point out the Pack so it can be looked at and changed.

Comment: What it two don't match, which two are wrong?

Comment: the 34.99 is wrong. So I would want the query to point out this packnumber (all of them)

Comment: So you want any pack numbers where min(retail)<>max(retail)?  You could make that into a SQL query quite easily.

Comment: Im not as familiar with SQL I have minimal experience but yeah that would probably be the best way to go. Just not sure how to build it honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT dbo_pic704current.packnum
, Min(dbo_pic704current.Ret2) AS LowRet2
, Max(dbo_pic704current.Ret2) AS HighRet2
, dbo_CatalogInfo.MediaId
, dbo_pic704current.DiscountReasonCode
, dbo_CatalogInfo.Brand
FROM dbo_pic704current INNER JOIN dbo_CatalogInfo ON (dbo_pic704current.year = 
dbo_CatalogInfo.mailyear) AND (dbo_pic704current.catid = dbo_CatalogInfo.catalog)
WHERE (((dbo_CatalogInfo.MediaId)='CAT Catalog'))
GROUP BY dbo_pic704current.packnum, dbo_CatalogInfo.MediaId, 
dbo_pic704current.DiscountReasonCode, dbo_CatalogInfo.Brand, dbo_pic704current.Year
HAVING (((Min(dbo_pic704current.Ret2))<>Max([Ret2])))
ORDER BY dbo_pic704current.packnum;
```

Comment: @JeffUK This is what I put together based on your suggestion and it seems to work. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your existing solution using aggregation is likely to yield better performance, but to offer an alternative, here is an example using a correlated subquery:

```sql
select 
    pc.packnum, pc.ret2, ci.mediaid, pc.discountreasoncode, ci.brand
from 
    dbo_pic704current pc inner join dbo_cataloginfo ci on 
    pc.year = ci.mailyear and pc.catid = ci.catalog
where 
    ci.mediaid = 'cat catalog' and exists 
    (select 1 from dbo_pic704current t where t.packnum = pc.packnum and t.ret2 > pc.ret2)
order by 
    pc.packnum
```